# PowerBI | Categorise revenues as new customers in a new column

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I'm hoping you all have a great day and maybe someone can make mine great too.

sampleData:
date; opportunity; customerID; revenue
01.01.2001; a; A; 50
01.01.2001; b; A; 50
03.04.2001; c; A; 50
05.05.2001; d; B; 150
26.10.2001; e; A; 100

I wanted to add a new calculated column with DAX which says if an revenue entry is either from a new customer or from an existing one. My thinking was that a new-customer-revenue is defined as all revenues of the first day an customer bought something. Which makes row 1, 2 and 4 of the sample data table above new-customer-revenues.

My thoughts somehow where:

```
new customer =
  VAR var_Customer = 'sampleData'[customerID]
  VAR var_SubTable = FILTER('sampleData', 'sampleData'[customerID] = var_Customer)
  VAR var_firstDate = MIN(var_SubTable[date])
  RETURN
      IF('sampleData'[date] = var_firstDate, "New Customer", "Existing Customer")
```

But the problem is that MIN() needs a column and I cant return a single column from var_SubTable... I also didn't find other suitable solutions for the problem. For me it would be really nice to have a new column, but if theres only a solution by using a measure that's also interesting to hear...

Thanks!
Hisager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.
Try using the following DAX Formula:

```
new customer = 
  VAR __Customer = 'sampleData'[customerID]
  VAR __SubTable = FILTER('sampleData', 'sampleData'[customerID] = __Customer)
  VAR __FirstDate = CALCULATE(MIN(sampleData[date]), __SubTable)
  RETURN
      IF('sampleData'[date] = __FirstDate, "New Customer", "Existing Customer")
```

It's basically the same but using calculate to get the min date.